# .htaccess 301 Redirects and Special Character Issue

Tags: .htaccess

I have a URL which ends

```
/presentation/Item?k=ZW52aXJvbm1lbnRhbC1oZWFsdGgtc2FmZXR5LXNlY3VyaXR5LWVuZ2xpc2g=&
```

Which I need to redirect to `http://domain.co.uk/films/ehss/`

But when I use the following; it doesn't work; I've tried escaping special characters like the ? by adding a \ before it but still no joy.

If its of any use this is all being added to the very beginning of htaccess file on a wordpress site.

This is what I've been trying:

```
Redirect 301 /presentation/Item\?k=ZW52aXJvbm1lbnRhbC1oZWFsdGgtc2FmZXR5LXNlY3VyaXR5LWVuZ2xpc2g=& http://domain.co.uk/films/ehss/
```

I've looked into see if any of the other characters are special characters and they aren't. Also, I don't think I can use REGEX for this either as I have about 50 urls all in the same format as above that need to be redirected to seo friendly urls.

Comment: PS. All other standard redirects work with the above method where there are no special characters

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can parse `QUERY_STRING` using `mod_rewrite`

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^k=ZW52aXJvbm1lbnRhbC1oZWFsdGgtc2FmZXR5LXNlY3VyaXR5LWVuZ2xpc2g=&$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^presentation/Item$ http://domain.co.uk/films/ehss/? [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot match query string using `Redirect` directive. You can use `THE_REQUEST` variable to match both request uri and query string like this:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /presentation/Item\?k=ZW52aXJvbm1lbnRhbC1oZWFsdGgtc2FmZXR5LXNlY3VyaXR5LWVuZ2xpc2g=& [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /films/ehss/? [R=301,L]
```