# How do I set up 301 Redirects in the .htaccess file that contain Query Strings and Special Characters?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, query-string, special-characters

I am having issues with some 301 Redirects that have Special Characters and Query Strings. See both examples below:

```
 Redirect 301 /Store/Collection/PRD_711112/722332++OGI05624++Product+Name.jsp?bmUID=123849d87623 http://www.NewURLIwanttoDirectTo.com/
```

and

```
 Redirect 301 /~/media/Images/About%20Us/Location%20ABCD%20Article.ashx http://www.NewURLIwanttoDirectTo.com/
```

What is the correct way to write these redirects? Thank you!

Comment: Possible duplicate  : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29636031/htaccess-301-redirects-and-special-character-issue